# 'SPUrl' prefix in SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-config

I am using SharePoint Foundation 2010.
There is a master page **v4.master**. I want to add some control to the **head**:

```
<head>
    ...
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/demo.css%>" runat="server"/>
    ...
</head>
```

and then next code to the **web.config**:

```
<compilation batch="false" debug="false">
  ...
  <expressionBuilders>
    ...
    <add expressionPrefix="SPUrl" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.SPUrlExpressionBuilder, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"/>
  </expressionBuilders>
</compilation>
```

But there is not assembly **Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll** in **GAC** or **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14**. How I can include 'SPUrl' to the web.config?

Comment: There is the answer:
http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Creating-custom-themable-CSS-files-for-SharePoint-2010.aspx
http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/What-is-new-with-the-CssRegistration-control-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the answer: 
http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Creating-custom-themable-CSS-files-for-SharePoint-2010.aspx
http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/What-is-new-with-the-CssRegistration-control-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use a **relative path** instead of using an **absolute path**. You dont want to edit your web.config for something simple as a css file...